# How to split tensor to small chunk for matrix multiplication to solve memory issue

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrix:
torch.Size([1, 8, 50176, 64]) torch.Size([1, 8, 64, 50176])
I need to perform matrix mutiplicatio to get torch size [1, 8, 50176, 50176], but I got cuda out of memory error and requires 75GB GPU memory, I cannot afford that much GPU, my one is 8GB, I am wondering how to spit the matrix into small chunk and perform mutiplication and finally concat resuts in one torch tensor?

I have tried:

```
y = torch.matmul(a, b) 
y = torch.bmm(a.view(-1, 50176, 64), b.view(-1, 64, 50176)).view(1, 8, 50176, 50176)
y = torch.einsum('bdij, bdjk -> bdik', (a, b))
```

none of the above work, both got cuda out of memory error.

Thank you for helping.

Ling

Comment: A (float) tensor of shape (1, 8, 50176, 50176) takes up 4*(8*50176*50176) / 2^30 = 75GB of space. Splitting this into smaller matrix multiplications won't solve this issue, you still need 75GB just to store the final matrix.

Comment: As jodag said there's a bottleneck in the size of the final tensor size. If possible (precision-wise) cast ```a ``` and ```b ``` to ```torch.cuda.HalfTensor```, then compute multiplication each time of a batch of size 1, this should take 4.6875GB of VRAM. Then, you have 2 options: If you have a lot of RAM - push the tensor into it by using ```.to('cpu')``` on the resulting matrix, and finally concatenate all the resulting matrices on the batch dimension. In case you don't have a lot of RAM, save each result of multiplication on disk and handle the loading (/unloading) of the data.

Comment: thank you both for your comment, I have a laptop with 16G RAM (CPU only) it can compute matmul of [900, 8, 50176, 64] with [900,8, 64, 50176] without any issue, but the GPU machine could not do it, I switch GPU machine to CPU which has 32G RAM, still cannot do it, why the 16G RAM can do it?

Comment: @Ling CPU memory can be "virtual": OS can swap portions of your RAM memory to disk and keep you running even when you consume more than the actual size of the physical RAM you have. OS cannot do that to GPU memory.